# Does Linux maintain a system RAM high water mark?

Tags: linux, ram, virtual-memory

I know there is VmHWM entry in each process's /proc/[PID]/status file, however is there an aggregate of this that contains the high water mark for the system?

I understand the free command give the current RAM utilization, but I was hoping the system might maintain a HWM value somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your kernel supports cgroup v1 memory controller, and it is enabled (as far as I know all the major Linux distributions have it enabled), you should be able to use the root `memory.max_usage_in_bytes` value for that:

```
echo "$(("$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes)" / 2**20)) MB"
```

Comment: Note that at least with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running with kernel version `5.4.128` that emits too low values. I agree that according to kernel documentation this should be the correct solution.